# Update values in a list with reflection

Tags: c#, .net, list, reflection

I have an object with over 100 properties. I then have a list with a lot of these objects.
I need to calculate the Min, Max, Medium and Median on all the properties in the list.

So instead of writing:

```
Ag = _valuesForExtraCalculations.Min(c => c.Ag),
Al = _valuesForExtraCalculations.Min(c => c.Al),
Alkal = _valuesForExtraCalculations.Min(c => c.Alkal),
```

one hundred times, I thought I would be able to use reflection, so I wrote:

```
var Obj = new Analysis();
Type t = Obj.GetType();
PropertyInfo[] prop = t.GetProperties();
foreach (var propertyInfo in prop)
{
    propertyInfo = _valuesForExtraCalculations.Min(?????);
}
```

But I'm not sure what to write in the `foreach` loop, so I can set the new min value for that property to the new Analysis object I created.

Comment: Are all properties of the same type?

Comment: No, some are strings, but thats not the major problem, I can always check so the property is an int, but how should I write to set the property?

Comment: So, you want a new object containing in every property the average ofthis property of all other objects?

Comment: Yes, So I have a list with alot of object A, that holds alot of properties, I then want to take the min value of that sertain property, and add that value to a new A object, to the same property, there for the reflection

Comment: Can you still change the implementation of the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to know the exact type of the properties. Let's assume it is `int`:

```
var Obj = new Analysis();
Type t = Obj.GetType();
PropertyInfo[] prop = t.GetProperties();
foreach (var pi in prop.Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(int)) 
{
    int min = _valuesForExtraCalculations.Min(c => (int)pi.GetValue(c, null));
    propertyInfo.SetValue(Obj, min, null);
}
```

If you have different types that you want to calculate the minimum for, you won't get around checking the types and switching accordingly so the correct overload of `Min` gets called.

I would still not consider this the best or most performant solution.

`PropertyInfo.GetValue` and `PropertyInfo.SetValue` are slower than direct field access (a lot slower [according to this article](http://lotsacode.wordpress.com/2010/04/12/getting-data-through-reflection-getvalue/)), also it would involve a lot of boxing. You would call `PropertyInfo.GetValue` (countOfObjects * countOfProperties) times. Depending on the number of items and properties, that might be of concern.

Comment: Thanks for this! The extraction of the min value is working nice, but setting the correct property is not working, this part ( propertyInfo.SetValue(this, min, null); I'm getting Object does not match target type

Comment: @Fore I accidently inserted `this` instead of your variable. Edited my answer now. If the objects in the list and `Obj` are of the same type, my updated example should work.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I've understood your question, you can achieve this using expressions:

```
/// <summary>
/// A class with many-many properties
/// </summary>
class MyClass
{
    public Decimal A { get; set; }
    public Decimal B { get; set; }
    public Decimal C { get; set; }
}

class PropertyHelper<T, TProperty>
{
    private readonly Func<T, TProperty> selector;
    private readonly Action<T, TProperty> setter;

    public PropertyHelper(Func<T, TProperty> selector, Action<T, TProperty> setter)
    {
        this.selector = selector;
        this.setter = setter;
    }

    public Func<T, TProperty> Selector
    {
        get { return selector; }
    }

    public Action<T, TProperty> Setter
    {
        get { return setter; }
    }
}

class AggregateHelper<T, TProperty>
{
    private readonly Dictionary<PropertyInfo, PropertyHelper<T, TProperty>> helpers;

    public AggregateHelper()
    {
        this.helpers = typeof(T)
            .GetProperties()
            .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(TProperty))
            .ToDictionary(p => p, p => new PropertyHelper<T, TProperty>(MakeSelector(p), MakeSetter(p)));
    }

    private Func<T, TProperty> MakeSelector(PropertyInfo property)
    {
        var parameterExpr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
        var lambda = (Expression<Func<T, TProperty>>)Expression.Lambda(
            Expression.Property(parameterExpr, property), parameterExpr);

        return lambda.Compile();
    }

    private Action<T, TProperty> MakeSetter(PropertyInfo property)
    {
        var instanceExpr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
        var parameterValueExpr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TProperty));
        var lambda = (Expression<Action<T, TProperty>>)Expression.Lambda(
            Expression.Call(instanceExpr, property.GetSetMethod(), parameterValueExpr),
            instanceExpr,
            parameterValueExpr);

        return lambda.Compile();
    }

    public IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> Properties
    {
        get { return helpers.Keys; }
    }

    public PropertyHelper<T, TProperty> this[PropertyInfo property]
    {
        get { return helpers[property]; }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
    public static void Do()
    {
        var target = new MyClass();
        var list = new List<MyClass>
        {
            new MyClass { A = 1M, B = 2M, C = 3M },
            new MyClass { A = 10M, B = 20M, C = 30M },
            new MyClass { A = 100M, B = 200M, C = 300M }
        };

        // calculate 'min' for all decimal properties
        var helper = new AggregateHelper<MyClass, Decimal>();

        foreach (var property in helper.Properties)
        {
            var propertyHelper = helper[property];

            propertyHelper.Setter(target, list.Min(propertyHelper.Selector));
        }
    }
```

Compiled lambdas work faster than reflection, and there will be no boxing/unboxing.